# How to display custom meta boxes under the post title in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am in working with WordPress plugin development and I am a newbie to that. I have created some custom post types also added some extra fields and that working as expected. But I need to show the extra fields under the title bar. But currently, that was displayed in the right sidebar.

Can we change the default design?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add `normal` to 5th parameter of `add_meta_box`.

```
function custom_register_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'meta-box-id', __( 'My Meta Box', 'textdomain' ), 'custom_my_display_callback', 'post', 'normal' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'custom_register_meta_boxes' );
```

Check their parameter.

```
/**
 * Adds a meta box to one or more screens.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 * @since 4.4.0 The `$screen` parameter now accepts an array of screen IDs.
 *
 * @global array $wp_meta_boxes
 *
 * @param string                 $id            Meta box ID (used in the 'id' attribute for the meta box).
 * @param string                 $title         Title of the meta box.
 * @param callable               $callback      Function that fills the box with the desired content.
 *                                              The function should echo its output.
 * @param string|array|WP_Screen $screen        Optional. The screen or screens on which to show the box
 *                                              (such as a post type, 'link', or 'comment'). Accepts a single
 *                                              screen ID, WP_Screen object, or array of screen IDs. Default
 *                                              is the current screen.  If you have used add_menu_page() or
 *                                              add_submenu_page() to create a new screen (and hence screen_id),
 *                                              make sure your menu slug conforms to the limits of sanitize_key()
 *                                              otherwise the 'screen' menu may not correctly render on your page.
 * @param string                 $context       Optional. The context within the screen where the box
 *                                              should display. Available contexts vary from screen to
 *                                              screen. Post edit screen contexts include 'normal', 'side',
 *                                              and 'advanced'. Comments screen contexts include 'normal'
 *                                              and 'side'. Menus meta boxes (accordion sections) all use
 *                                              the 'side' context. Global default is 'advanced'.
 * @param string                 $priority      Optional. The priority within the context where the box should show.
 *                                              Accepts 'high', 'core', 'default', or 'low'. Default 'default'.
 * @param array                  $callback_args Optional. Data that should be set as the $args property
 *                                              of the box array (which is the second parameter passed
 *                                              to your callback). Default null.
 */
function add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $screen = null, $context = 'advanced', $priority = 'default', $callback_args = null ){}
```